# How to read "Gupta:Table" control in Gupta:MDIFrame using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to read the contents of an on-screen table using Autohotkey.

Using MouseGetPos and WinGetClass, I found out that the control is a "Gupta:Table1" in a "Gupta:MDIFrame" window. Is there any way I can read the contents of this table? Using ControlGetText returns an empty string...

Comment: Try **[Capture2Text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/#download)**

Comment: Goal is to "do something" with the results in autohotkey - so a separate application seems no option...

Comment: If you start and close the application with autohotkey, you can "do something" after reading the clipboard, because the OCR text is by default placed on the clipboard.

Comment: I wonder whether there isn't a "better" way to extract the original text parts out of the control?... OCR seems to go from Paris to Rome through New York...

Comment: You could try AccViewer just in case it works, it's always the first thing I try.